# How to save Html code in database through Django

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I want to save `html code` in database through django.

In `models.py` i have this field

```
description = models.TextField()
```

But when i save data in **description field** through **Django Admin**. It display data like this

```
<h1>This is example</h1>
```

rather then converting it in html. [Here's the Out Put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVN0E.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Template engine escaping html default. You have to filter it with safe tag when you showing.

```
{{ description |safe }}
```

or use autoescape tag

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ description }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: where can i use these tags ? in view.py or in models.py

Comment: or in my view.html

Comment: It should be in your view.

Comment: Thanks its working..i just put this code in view.html like this                                  {% autoescape off %}{{object.description | linebreaks }}{% endautoescape %}

Comment: @devdap You need to be careful when you say it should be in your view. View in Django is equivalent to Controllers in other frameworks. So I would say "it should be in your template i.e. template.html"