# Storing text with customizable font in database

Tags: javascript, database, forms

I have a field in my database (called "Text") which stores text that the user enters. The user will be able to change the font, add highlights, bold, italic, etc. to wherever they want in the text they are writing. Is the proper way to handle this to have the JS allow the user to customize their text, then when storing into my database, add tags to the areas they customized?

Ex:

User types "Hello, I am **writing some text**" using something like [WYSIWYG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)

Database will store `Hello, I am \*BOLD*\writing some text \*BOLD*\` where `\*BOLD*\` is the tag.

Or is there an already existing JS framework that will handle doing this for me?

Comment: You are not currently using a development framework? If you are writing raw database queries to achieve your goal then you should be looking for a framework to handle your database inserts, updates, etc to help prevent sql injection, proper character escaping, data validation and the like. Laravel is one option but you would need to learn PHP, but it would give you a starting point into finding other similar frameworks written in different languages.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that I'm using Django with PostgreSQL for the backend and database.

Comment: Ah, then you are probably looking for this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474988/how-to-save-html-code-in-database-through-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474988/how-to-save-html-code-in-database-through-django)

Comment: Awesome that's perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to store html. The benefit of storing html is that it is already marked up when you need to display it back to the user later on. The downside is that you have to be careful to sanitize it to make sure that it doesn't include any scripting hacks. Check out the [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) package from npm

(Depending on the length of your string, it may be a good idea to compress the sanitized output to save bandwidth)

Comment: I'm thinking of keeping the length of the string < 7500 characters (around 750 words). Are there any guidelines for determining if this length makes it better to compress the sanitized output?

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer:

I assume you decided to use some HTML Text to send to the database.

As I saw your reply to [`@mankowitz`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055937/13593975):

> I'm thinking of keeping the length of the string < 7500 characters (around 750 words). Are there any guidelines for determining if this length makes it better to compress the sanitized output?

#### You forgot an important thing:

You'll mostly *need* to minify your HTML/CSS/JS/ *, etc* text, to make the data that sent to the server is *even smaller*.
I find gz compression very good with HTML because HTML contains lots of duplicates of HTML tags.

I threw some HTML code into my editor, added some lore Ipsum, and compressed it with an output of a 250% compression ratio and 300% at max.

#### Characters don't count

Characters, they can have 3 bytes, or eight bits, depending on the encoding, and language of the text. So in this answer, everything will be counted in bytes/bits.

### Conclusion

About a 170% compression ratio for a 570-byte string of HTML.
I recommend about 600 to 700 bytes should be the point where you start compressing the data.

---

## Original Answer:

#### Reason:

The owner of this question wants to use HTML text, in which this original answer uses `BaseXX` encoding.

### You should use a special file format.

If you can, you should send the gunzipped file to the server.
If you can only send a string to the server, use base64 encoding or base85 encoding or base91 encoding.

Use a special file format, which is not covered in this answer, but here are ways to transfer the files.

*Pure text encoding using Markdown is not recommended due to security issues.*

- Base64

  - Pros

    - built-in web apis/functions [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)
    - Easy to use
  - Cons

    - Large output string size
    - The built-in web apis/functions are *mostly* incompatible with pure binary files, will need to use binary converter and custom coded base64 encoder/decoder because the built-in apis/functions *mostly* do not support binary formats.
- Base85

  - Pros

    - Smaller output string size
    - Code has already been made
  - Cons

    - No built-in web apis/functions
    - Harder to wire up all the functions
- Base91

  - Pros

    - ***EVEN SMALLER OUTPUT SIZE***
    - ***MADE*** *for binary formats*
  - Cons

    - Not really used for text
    - Most packages found on google are npm-packages/false-advertising
    - The full *HOW-TO* is hardly known when searching on search-engines.
- *Pure text*

  - Pros

    - Close to `0%` size inflations.
    - Easy to setup.
  - Cons

    - ***WILL NEED TO CODE SPECIAL SECURITY MEASURES TO PREVENT SQL/XSS/,etc ATACKS***
    - *Escape special characters/newlines/,etc.*

#### Recommendations:

Use Base85 or BasE91, if possible. 
 **DO NOT USE THE PURE TEXT OPTION BECAUSE IT DOES NOT SUPPORT FONTS** *Mostly*
(Compress the output to save bandwidth)

#### Also read:

[@mankowitz answer for more information on bandwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055937/13593975)

Comment: @slick_reaper Depends on what type of compression you use

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! I haven't gotten around to researching compression for the text field but I'll check out the links you gave.

Comment: Hi TheUnch0senOne, please note that although external links are welcome, your site should **not** be used to continue an explanation of the text in your answer - instead, post the text inside of the answer itself. The answer itself should be beneficial enough to understand without having to open any external links. (Additionally, if you would like to separate portions of your answer, I suggest that you should use a [horizontal line](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#horizontal-rules) instead of multiple `<br>` tags.)